# Erro com ActionListener

Tags: java, swing

```
  import java.awt.Color;
    import java.awt.Container;
    import java.awt.GridLayout;
    import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
    import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
    import java.io.File;

    import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
    import javax.swing.JButton;
    import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
    import javax.swing.JFrame;
    import javax.swing.JLabel;

    public class SwingFileDialog  extends JFrame {
        private JButton bDialog; //botão p/ acionar o diálogo
        private JLabel bDialogo;  //botão p/ resultados
        private JFileChooser dialogo;  //diálogo de arquivos

        public SwingFileDialog() {
            super("SwingFileDialog"); //ajusta titulo
            Container cp = getContentPane(); //painel de conteudo
            cp.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 1)); //layout grade 4 x1
            JLabel lResultado;
            cp.add(lResultado = new JLabel("Sem seleção"));
            lResultado.setBorder(
                    BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(2, 2, 3, 2, Color.GREEN));
            bDialogo.addActionListener(new ActionListener() { //AQUI ESTA DANDO ERROR

                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                   dialogo = new JFileChooser();
                   int res = dialogo.showOpenDialog(SwingFileDialog.this);
                   if(res==JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                       File  arq = dialogo.getSelectedFile();
                       lResultado.setText(arq.getName());
                           }    }   
                } );
            setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            pack();
            }
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            new SwingFileDialog().setVisible(true);

        }
}
```

Erro:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
The method addActionListener(new ActionListener(){}) is undefined for the type JLabel

at SwingFileDialog.<init>(SwingFileDialog.java:29)
at SwingFileDialog.main(SwingFileDialog.java:43)
```

Comment: Forneça mais informações sobre o erro.

Comment: Eu não sei porque esta dando erro nesse código

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sua variável `bDialogo` não é um botão, é um *label* ("rótulo"). *Labels* só servem para mostrar informação, não existe nenhuma ação associada a eles (como a ação de clicar). Você está chamando o método `addActionListener` de um `JLabel` - que não possui esse método - daí o erro de compilação.

O fato de você estar tendo um erro de **execução** - e não de compilação - provavelmente é devido ao IDE (Eclipse?) responsável por compilar essa classe: [nessa resposta no SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1124788/520779), por exemplo, indica-se que o Eclipse compila o código e introduz essa exceção *apesar* do erro de compilação (me parece algo bem idiota de se fazer, mas eles devem ter seus motivos...). Se você estiver usando o Eclipse, tente "limpar" ou fazer "refresh" no código antes de compilá-lo (não uso esse IDE há muito tempo, não me lembro como ele funciona).

E para corrigir o erro, naturalmente, é só trocar o tipo de `bDialogo` de `JLabel` para `JButton`.

Comment: Vlw, deu certo aqui...